# Error in confusion matrix data can't have more levels CARET

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix, rpart

dataset can be find here : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing#

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(bank), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train.data <- bank[ind == 1, ]
test.data <- bank[ind == 2, ]
```

I was searching my problem i tried to set it to factor in confusion matrix. But problem didn't solved at all

```
cartmodel <- rpart(y ~., data = train.data)
cartmodel
cart.pred = predict(cartmodel, test.data)
summary(cart.pred)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(cart.pred),as.factor(test.data$y))
confusionMatrix
```

What i need to change? Dataset is Bank.. so Num and Factor attributes.

Update : i tried change all atributed to factor.. still error

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set in order to make it reproducible. If the data set is publicly available, please include a description on how to access it.

Comment: Dataset is from UCI .. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the csv from UCI (can also try this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vkrit/r-programming/master/bank-full.csv)):

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
bank = read.csv("../bank/bank-full.csv",sep=";")

set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(bank), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train.data <- bank[ind == 1, ]
test.data <- bank[ind == 2, ]
```

When you call `predict()` you are getting the probabilities, not the labels:

```
cartmodel <- rpart(y ~., data = train.data)
cart.pred = predict(cartmodel, test.data)
head(cart.pred)

          no        yes
5  0.9393461 0.06065387
14 0.9393461 0.06065387
16 0.9393461 0.06065387
26 0.9393461 0.06065387
28 0.9393461 0.06065387
29 0.9393461 0.06065387
```

To get labels:

```
cart.pred = predict(cartmodel, test.data,type="class")
confusionMatrix(cart.pred,test.data$y)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    no   yes
       no  11710  1039
       yes   302   517
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.9012         
                 95% CI : (0.896, 0.9061)
    No Information Rate : 0.8853         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.831e-09      
                                         
                  Kappa : 0.3869
```